# I have created function to modify a node in Linkedlist in C++ but its not working:

Tags: c++, oop, linked-list, singly-linked-list, function-definition

This Function is Created in LinkedList to modify a node at a given position. But, this function is not working properly and it is giving some random values.

```
  void update_data(int old, int new_data) {//Function toupdate node
                Node *curr=header;//Data members
               int pos = 0;
               while(curr->next!=NULL) {
                  if(curr->isbn == old)
                  {
                     curr->isbn = new_data;
                     cout<<old<<" Found at position "<<pos<<" Replaced with "<<new_data<<endl;;
                  }
                  curr = curr->next;
                  pos++;
               }
               }
```

Comment: Time to get debugging, then! Good luck!

Comment: @M. Ameen Akbar The variable pos is not used.

Comment: @M. Ameen Akbar What do you mean saying that the function does not work properly?

Comment: Consider what happens at `while(curr->next!=NULL)` if the list is empty and `curr` is `NULL`..

Comment: Sit down with your [Rubber Duck](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging) and discuss whether or not is it worth continuing to search through the list after finding and updating the item.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For starters the variable `pos` is not used within the function.

Secondly the condition of the while loop

```
while(curr->next!=NULL) {
```

is incorrect and in general can invoke undefined behavior because the pointer `header` can be equal to `nullptr`. And moreover if the list contains only one node pointed to by the pointer header and its data member `isbn` is equal to the value of the variable `old` it will not be changed.

The function should not output any message.

The function can look the following way

```
void update_data( int old, int new_data ) 
{//Function toupdate node
    for ( Node *curr = header; curr != nullptr; curr = curr->next ) 
    {
        if ( curr->isbn == old )
        {
            curr->isbn = new_data;
        }
    }
}
```